# simple yet twisted SQL query

Tags: sql

I have a table say like

```
X Y
1 3
2 4
```

Now when a view table in SQL it would show

```
A1 A2
1  3
2  4
```

But I want output to be like

```
A1  A2
X   Y
1   3
2   4
```

Is it possible to do so? Please let me know if I am able to point out my problem.

Comment: Do you want column name also..?

Comment: It is quite unclear what are you trying to achieve and what is *exact* problem. Can you elaborate more? Also note: `sql` tag is very broad, possible solution of your problem can be tightly coupled with exact RDBMS you're using.

Comment: @Mansoor: Yes that is correct. I want column names too.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev: I am just trying to get the complete table including the variable names in SQL output. Generally we get only the values/data stored in the specific table, but along with the data I want the variable names too. (Actually it was queried to me in a interview so unclear about exact RDBMS, so just mentioned SQL tag only).

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @ColNames VARCHAR(100),@Query VARCHAR(100) = ''
```

CREATE TABLE Tbl1 (X INT, Y INT) CREATE TABLE Tbl2 (A1 VARCHAR(10), A2 VARCHAR(10)) INSERT INTO Tbl1 (X , Y ) SELECT 1,3 UNION ALL SELECT 2,4
SELECT DISTINCT @ColNames = STUFF( ( SELECT  ',' + Col.name + ''
FROM SYS.COLUMNS Col WHERE OBJECT_NAME(Col.OBJECT_ID) = 'Tbl1' FOR XML PATH('') ), 1,1,'') SET @Query = 'SELECT ''' + REPLACE(@ColNames,',',''',''') + ''''
INSERT INTO Tbl2 (A1 , A2 )
EXEC (@Query)
INSERT INTO Tbl2 (A1 , A2 )
SELECT 1,3 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,4
SELECT * FROM Tbl2